# PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController always returns nil?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, controller, applepay

I am trying to set up Apple Pay for my application but for some reason the PKPaymentViewController is always returned as nil (if statement in code was to test this)?? Any ideas why?

```
@IBAction func payAction(_ sender: Any) {

    price = donationAmount.text
    print(price)

    let request = PKPaymentRequest()
    request.merchantIdentifier = applePayMerchantID
    request.supportedNetworks = SupportedPaymentNetworks
    request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS
    request.countryCode = "GBR"
    request.currencyCode = "GBP"
    request.requiredBillingAddressFields = PKAddressField.all

    //request.applicationData = "This is a test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let paymentSummary = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label:"Sponsorship", amount: 10.00)]

    request.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummary

    let applePayController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)

    applePayController.delegate = self;


    if(applePayController == nil){
        print("___")
    } else{
        self.present(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {
    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success)
}

func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Use this function `canMakePayments(usingNetworks:)` to check if you can make payments. And tell us about the result

Comment: It is returned as true using that function

Comment: Do you configure Apple Pay properly on your iPhone device?

Comment: Yes it is all set up correctly and works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configure `countryCode` with wrong ISO

> ## countryCode
>
> The two-letter ISO 3166 country code.

for the United Kingdom country code is `GB`

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentrequest/1619246-countrycode)